# Ember project with themes and skins

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Any ideas on how to create an Ember / Handlebars project with suport for multiple themes / skins that can be changed through a dropbox in the UI?

Current version of Ember is 1.0.0-rc.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nothing too unique to Ember here. Use CSS for themes/skins, and change the current theme stylesheet when the dropbox changes.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there is a switch stylesheet ember-cli that you can use:
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-theme-changer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-theme-changer/)

---

#### Install Theme Changer

```
ember install ember-theme-changer
```

#### Modify the code below in ember-cli-build.js:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        css: {
          'light': '/assets/light.css', // FOR LIGHT THEME => app.scss
          'dark': '/assets/dark.css' // FOR DAR THEME => dark.scss
        }
      }
    },
```

#### Create your own SCSS with difference configuration.

1. Go to app/styles folder
2. Create dark.css and app.scss

dark.scss

```
body{
 background-color: black;
}
```

app.scss

```
body{
 background-color: light;
}
```

#### All you need just to make two button to switch the css file that you apply to

Think of it this easy way:

### In Html template application.hbs

```
<link href="light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<button class='light'>LIGHT MODE</button>
<button class='dark'>DARK MODE</button>
```

### In Javascript File

```
$('.light').click(function (){
   $('link[href="light.css"]').attr('href','black.css');
});
$('.black').click(function (){
   $('link[href="black.css"]').attr('href','light.css');
});
```

comments: You can use other addon (more complicated) which it can be found on:

1. https://www.emberaddons.com/
2. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-themed-syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-themed-syntax/)